# using dask multi threaded module

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to use dask's multi-threaded module. This code

```
def foo(arg):
  return arg*2

jobs = []
t = delayed(foo)(100)
jobs.append(t)

j = delayed(jobs, pure=True)
#j = j.compute()
j = j.compute(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
print("class:", type(j[0]))
```

prints `('class:', <type 'tuple'>)` when executed, but if I run the commented line instead (i.e., not using `multiprocessing.get`) then I actually get the right result `100 ('class:', <type 'int'>)` Did I do something wrong?

Related question: what is the default `get` in dask when nothing is specified?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the delayed function call in another delayed?

Comment: This is caused by https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1192. The multiprocessing scheduler performs a fuse optimization, which results in this issue. Should have this fixed shortly hopefully, but for now just don't use the multiprocessed scheduler. The default scheduler for delayed objects is the threaded schedule which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: That issue is still relevant, but fixed in a different way here: https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/1194. Same result now in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to compute a list of delayed objects then I recommend using dask's compute function rather than the compute method.

```
from dask import delayed, compute
import dask.multiprocessing

def foo(arg):
  return arg*2

jobs = [delayed(foo)(100)]

>>> compute(*jobs, get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
(200,)
```